# Create a nested dict containing list from a file

Tags: python, list, dictionary, txt

For example, for the txt file of

```
Math, Calculus, 5 
Math, Vector, 3
Language, English, 4
Language, Spanish, 4
```

into the dictionary of:

```
 data={'Math':{'name':[Calculus, Vector], 'score':[5,3]}, 'Language':{'name':[English, Spanish], 'score':[4,4]}}
```

I am having trouble with appending value to create list inside the smaller dict. I'm very new to this and I would not understand importing command. Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: Could the input file has only COMMA or SPACE as separator and not both ? Or are you 100% sure that it'll always be COMMA+SPACE as separator ?

Comment: You may think about [accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to reward those how helped you, or at least comment to explain what's missing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each line, find the 3 values, then add them to a dict structure

```
from pathlib import Path

result = {}
for row in Path("test.txt").read_text().splitlines():
    subject_type, subject, score = row.split(", ")

    if subject_type not in result:
        result[subject_type] = {'name': [], 'score': []}

    result[subject_type]['name'].append(subject)
    result[subject_type]['score'].append(int(score))
```

---

You can simplify it with the use of a `defaultdict` that creates the mapping if the key isn't already present

```
result = defaultdict(lambda: {'name': [], 'score': []}) # from collections import defaultdict
for row in Path("test.txt").read_text().splitlines():
    subject_type, subject, score = row.split(", ")
    result[subject_type]['name'].append(subject)
    result[subject_type]['score'].append(int(score))
```

---

With **pandas.DataFrame** you can directly the formatted data and output the format you want

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.txt", sep=", ", engine="python", names=['key', 'name', 'score'])
df = df.groupby('key').agg(list)
result = df.to_dict(orient='index')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Could you suggest some other ways that does not need to import commands?

Comment: @mylearning The first one doesn't really need, you can read a file without pahtlib.Path. Also you can't expect to code in python without the use of libraries, that's the power of Python

Answer (score 0):

From your data:

```
data={'Math':{'name':['Calculus', 'Vector'], 'score':[5,3]}, 
      'Language':{'name':['English', 'Spanish'], 'score':[4,4]}}
```

If you want to append to the list inside your dictionary, you can do:

```
data['Math']['name'].append('Algebra')

data['Math']['score'].append(4)
```

If you want to add a new dictionary, you can do:

```
data['Science'] = {'name':['Chemisty', 'Biology'], 'score':[2,3]}
```

I am not sure if that is what you wanted but I hope it helps!